# Align images like Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I want to align my images like bootstrap, I can't do it with bootstrap because user have the option to resize the images and using Bootstrap class "col-md, col-xs, etc." user can't resize the image width, I tried creating a div with width:100% and then I add width:25% to each image (I want 4 images per row), and the image is in the correct size but not in the correct position.

This is what I have at the moment:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Without Bootstrap</h2>
    <div class="">
      <img class="responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" style="width:250px; height:250px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <img class="responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" style="width:250px; height:250px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <img class="responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" style="width:250px; height:250px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <img class="responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" style="width:250px; height:250px;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example of what I want vs what I have

[Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEobEg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you resize the image using width: 25% !important; to override the bootstrap defaults?

Comment: I get the same result

Comment: The only difference is that Bootstrap is using `float:left` on the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a class to your divs that contain the images, you can use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

I added CSS to your file:

```
.blockRow {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 2.2em;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>With Bootstrap</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">
      <img class="responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" style="width:250px; height:250px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">
      <img class="responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" style="width:250px; height:250px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">
      <img class="responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" style="width:250px; height:250px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">
      <img class="responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" style="width:250px; height:250px;" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <h2>Without Bootstrap</h2>
   <div class="blockRow">
      <img class="responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" style="width:250px; height:250px;" />
    </div>
  <div class="blockRow">
      <img class="responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" style="width:250px; height:250px;" />
    </div>
  <div class="blockRow">
      <img class="responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" style="width:250px; height:250px;" />
    </div>
  <div class="blockRow">
      <img class="responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" style="width:250px; height:250px;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You'll have to play around with the padding to get it how you want it to look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEobEg

Comment: This is what I want, padding doesn't matter because user can move and resize the images, the align was the important thing, thanks.